# Why is HTTP request header "If-None-Match" called that?

Tags: http, http-headers

The behavior of the `If-None-Match` request header field is specified in [Section 3.2 of RFC7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.2).

I understand this part of the spec and don't need it explained.  What I don't understand is why the header is named "If-None-Match".  That makes about as much sense to me as "Wherefore-Giraffe-Bathtub".

Is there a rationale for the name, or at least a decent mnemonic that will help me remember what it means a week from now?

Comment: I'm not sure what to do about the fact that this got closed.  Technically, it's asking for a fact, not an opinion: "what was the rationale for naming it this", and, if that couldn't be answered, asks for a mnemonic for remembering it.  In any case, the rationale for closing opinion-based questions is "This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers."  Is that *really* a concern here, given that the two answers consist of fact and citation, without issue? Happy to reword if there are suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the If-None-Match header you provide a list of ETags.

The server will provide the requested page only **if none** (of the provided ETags) **match**.

Otherwise it will return a `304 Not Modified`.

This is similar to other `If-` headers such as `If-Modified-Since`, where the page is only returned if it was modified since the given timestamp.

Comment: Well that was unexpected-- it actually makes sense now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the older RFC documents [RFC2068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068) and [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616):

> A client that has one or more entities previously obtained from the resource can verify that **none** of those entities is current by including a list of their associated entity tags in the If-None-Match header field.

> **If none** of the entity tags **match** (the current/requested entity), then the server MAY perform the requested method as if the If-None-Match header field did not exist